# Iterate function x times by for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.ip_button').click(function(){
   var buttonValue, slideTimes;
   buttonValue = $(this).html();
   slideTimes = parseInt(buttonValue) - 1;
   for (var i = 0 ; i < slideTimes; i++) { 
          slider.gallery_next(); 
       }             
});
```

Hi I'm trying to slide multiple images on a slider using function that determines value of button -1 and running slide that many times. Unfortunately, function do it only one time no matter what value is in button. Currently value in button is:

```
<button class="ip_button">5</button>
```

Function for gallery_next(); is encapsulated and goes like this:

```
this.gallery_next = function() {
    if (galleryRotating) { return; }
    galleryRotating = true;
    var elem = $(galleryId + " > li").first();
    $(galleryId).append(elem.clone());
    $(galleryId).animate({"left" : -imgWidth}, 650, function() {
        elem.remove();
        galleryRotating = false;
        $(galleryId).css({"left" : 0});
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `animate` would not finish by the time `for` loop invokes the function again, so `galleryRotation` will still be true, and the functions would do nothing. You need a different approach: either set a timer to invoke your function in say 700ms or (which is better) invoke rotation again in the callback you pass to `animate`.

Comment: It is actually put into a queue: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
In your question you did check whether animation effect is already active, so the animation was not enqueued. In the jsfiddle sample you do not check it, so animation is queued.